# How can I format numbers or strings in a DataRepeater?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarepeater

Tech: .NET, SQL Server 2008 R2, Winforms

Ok, for the life of me, I cannot figure this out.

First and foremost, I'm using a DataTable to store the data, which is coming from an SQL server 2008 database, and I'm binding it to a DataRepeater.

I've tried changing the binding like this:

```
label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", history, "Value", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.Never, "", "N");
```

which works great on textboxes and labels elsewhere, but not on the DataRepeater. (label1 is part of the ItemTemplate associated with the DataRepeater)

Since binding the data like that isn't working, I want to just take my DataTable and just force the column to have the format listed above.

And manually changing the format of the data: (it's a Float)

```
for (int i=0;i < history.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    history.Rows[i]["Value"] = String.Format("{0:N}", history.Rows[i]["Value"]);
}
```

Doesn't work either, the datarepeater just changes it back.

I want this:

```
12,123,123.00
```

and I get this:

```
12123123
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is your `DataTable` "history" that converts the values back to `double`. When the column's data type is `double` (which I suspect) then it accepts a string representation of a `double` and kindly converts it back.

You should add a computed column to your `DataTable` and fill it with the string representation of the numeric value.

BTW: you forgot a `i++` in your `for` statement.

Comment: I'll consider this a possible solution, but it's not best when you have large amounts of data that require to be formatted. Which I have to take into account. Let's wait and see if there are other solutions out there. Before I close this. Also, it's actually a float, and I erased the Convert.To statement as it's redundant in this case, but was used in a previous part of the application and copy pasted.

Comment: Making this the answer as this was the only solution that worked with a datarepeater

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for my bad english. This works fine for me.

```
private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string f = String.Format("{0:#0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)sender).Text));
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = f;
}
```

**example:**

`textBox10.Text= 48`
`result= 48.00`

Change this code for each other data types.

That uses `TextChanged` event of the textbox in to `Datarepeater`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to convert 12123123 to 12,123,123 automatically; put this code in _TextChanged event of your textbox:

```
int i = ((TextBox)sender).SelectionStart;
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text != "")
        {
            string f = String.Format("{0:N0}", Convert.ToDouble(((TextBox)sender).Text));
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = f;
            int len;
            len = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Replace(",", "").Length;
            if ((len %= 3) == 1)
            {
                i += 1;
            }
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectionStart = i;
        }
```